# I want to get data from mysql with respect to date, I have try a code it doesn't work

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, datepicker

```
private void searchbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myconnectionstring = "DataSource=127.0.0.1;Database=highlandsmartapp;username=root;password=";
    connection = new MySqlConnection(myconnectionstring);
    connection.Open();
    try
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter sd = new MySqlDataAdapter(
            "SELECT * FROM highlandsmartapp.order WHERE order_date BETWEEN'" 
            + DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() 
            + "'AND'" + DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString() + "' ", connection);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sd.Fill(dt);
        BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();
        bsource.DataSource = dt;
        DataGridView.DataSource = bsource;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: what error do you get? don't just say "it doesn't work"

Comment: Keep in mind that the automatic conversion of a DateTime to a string uses your culture info and this is not always what the database expect. Why don't you search a bit about parameterized queries?

Comment: "It doesn't work" .. it doesn't show any data between the dates

Comment: I have been searching like hungry dog everywhere but still a man of nowhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you concatenate together strings to form your sql command. When converting the date from the DateTimePicker value you ask the framework to convert do that but the framework converts the dates according to the local convention for your culture.

This is very often not what the database expects and you get nothing in return (and you are lucky if you don't get any exception)

Instead you should pass the DateTime values as parameters and let the database figure it how to use those values without any kind of conversion

```
MySqlDataAdapter sd = new MySqlDataAdapter(
   @"SELECT * FROM highlandsmartapp.order WHERE order_date BETWEEN @dp1 AND @dp2", connection);
sd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@dp1", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
sd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@dp2", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker2.Value.Date;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sd.Fill(dt);
....
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is "da" here, I'm a beginner

Comment: My bad, it is the MySqlDataAdapter variable, fixed now

Comment: You are my Love Steve ! :D